# Matplotlib - 3D Graph only works once

Tags: python, matplotlib, multidimensional-array

I'm working on the diffusion equation for a length of L and want to produce a 3D plot of how the solution over the length changes with time so I have an array of values stored for each time step as a matrix just called matrix2 - x and times are the arrays for the values along the length and of all the time steps.

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    x,times=np.meshgrid(x,times)
    ax.plot_surface(x,times,matrix2,antialiased=False);
    plt.show()
```

Now if I run this code, I get the 3D plot I would expect out. If I then try and run the code a second time though either for the exact same values or after running the diffusion for longer and changing times and matrix 2, I don't get an output, there is usually a MemoryError and everything on the computer slows down. Is there something I should be doing which allows me to produce more than one of these sorts of plots?[Image of error on running the code for a second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt9Z0.png)

Comment: Could you copy a full error?

Comment: @PlikePotato I've added an image to the main post now of the error - running the code a single time produces the 3D plot I expect but rerunning the code fails - if I comment out the meshgrid line on the second run through, it works again so I don't know if that gives a clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: Rename your `x`  and `times` variables. Either for every instance in the script before this line or after.

Comment: Thanks for the help @PaulBrodersen